# Density of $Y=|X|$, where $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I am reviewing for an upcoming exam, and came across this question in the textbook. Can someone please help me with this question? Thanks.

> If $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then find the density of $Y=|X|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having trouble finding distributions (or densities), it's usually not a bad idea to start from the cdf, $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$.

Let $Y = |X|$, $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and let $F_X$ be the cdf of $X$. Then, for $y \geq 0$,
\begin{align*}
P(Y \leq y) &= P(|X| \leq y) \\
&= P(-y \leq X \leq y) \\
&= P(-y \leq X \leq 0) + P(0 < X \leq y) \tag{1}\\
&= P(0 \leq X \leq y) + P(0 < X < \leq y) \tag{2} \\
&= 2P(0\leq X \leq y) \tag{3} \\
&= 2(F_X(y) - F_X(0)). 
\end{align*}
In (1) we were able to split the union of events into a sum, since they are mutually exclusive.
In (2) we used symmetry of the centred normal random variable $X$.
In (3) we used continuity of $X$ to change the $<$ to a $\leq$.

To conclude you need only use the relationship between $F_Y$ and its density $f_y$.

Comment: what do you mean by the relationship between F_y and its density. Also can you explain why we can do (3)?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}F(t)=f(t)$

Comment: I am still confused, on what to do.

Comment: For the normal random variable, $P(X \leq x) = F_X(x) \dot{=} \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dt$. In this case $\mu = 0$. You have the expression for $P(Y \leq y)$ and you want its density. What now?